# Is this an appropriate strategy for evaluating a complex limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^2e^{-2i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}re^{-3i\theta}=0$$

I wanted to avoid an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: i liked my $\ell$s ):

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $$ = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{|z|^4}{z^3} = 0$$